# WithDegreeOfParallelism(N>CPU count)

Tags: c#, plinq

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50);
File.ReadLines().AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(100).ForAll((s)->{
/*
some code which is waiting external API call 
and do not utilize CPU 
*/
});
```

I have never got threads count more than CPU count in my system.
Can I use PLINQ and get more than one thread per CPU?

Comment: What's the point of that? Performance will not increase.

Comment: @GSerg: It might do if there's some sort of blocking IO going on. Not recommended though.

Comment: I'd look into TPL DataFlow if I was you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx. Or if you want to use pure TPL, check out Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach

Comment: I suspect a call to SetMinThreads might help here (although I think you're doing something wrong if this actually yields a speed increase).

Comment: @spender - when there is blocked I/O then the scheduler will add threads, unless MaxDegree is too low.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes, but the ramp-up is not immediate. The real solution here is not to block on IO.

Comment: GSerg, why you think perfomance will not increase?
If we have 5 tasks awaiting external API responce in parallel mode we will get 1 second, if they will be waiting sequental - we will get 5 seconds.

Comment: @Vladimir: I can answer that. IMO it's really bad practice to do any kind of blocking operation in delegates that will get used in the ThreadPool. Correctly written code would not block on IO, meaning that you don't have to increase the number of threads (only to have most of your threads parked, waiting on IO). I think that the recommendation to use TPL DataFlow for this is a good one, and to ensure that your code **never** blocks. That's the best way to acheive high throughput. You shouldn't need more than [NumCPUs] threads. It doesn't scale.

Comment: If you get work queued up in the ThreadPool by blocking on IO, you'll find that a lot of other stuff that relies on a fluid ThreadPool stops working nicely and displays a lot of latency as the ThreadPool adjusts to higher workloads. Timers won't fire on time and all other IO will be affected.

Comment: I am not blocking IO. Every task will only send request to external slow API and wait for ~3 seconds for response. I am confident that in this time I could send more requests until I get first response.

Comment: @Vladimir That is the *definition* of blocking IO; you start an IO operation and then have a thread sitting there doing nothing waiting for it to finish, rather than using asynchrony so that you can do something when it's done without having a thread waiting on the operation.

Comment: @Vladimir: The statement "I am not blocking IO." directly contradicts "Every task will only send request to external slow API and wait for ~3 seconds for response". You are blocking on IO. For ~3 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. 
I were very excited with PLINQ but it seems it does not fit to my story. 
Can you advice another approaches? I definitely need to have up to 20 requests in the same time.
Thank you

Comment: @Vladimir - async/await is good one, or TPL DataFlow. look into those

Comment: Is this a Producer-Consumer pattern problem? If so, there's always BlockingCollection.

Answer (score 4):

If you're calling external web API, you might be hitting the limit of concurrent simultaneous connections, which is set to 2. In the begining of your application do the following:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 4096;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Try if that helps. If not, there might be some other bottleneck within the routine you're trying to parallelize.

Also, just like other responders said, ThreadPool decides how many threads to spin up based on load. In my experience with TPL I've seen that thread cound increases by time: longer the app runs, and heavier load gets, more threads are spun up.

Comment: Thank you, but external API is not a blocker here

Answer (score 1):

PLINQ uses a hill-climbing algorithm to determine the optimum size of the thread pool which is used by the TPL. I think that if you put a lot of I/O in your tasks, seeing more threads than the cpu count is likeable.

That said, I've never seen more threads than the cpu count :) . But maybe I never had the right situation.

Comment: AFAIK, PLINQ doesn't use any such algorithm, `ThreadPool` does.

Comment: That's really splitting hairs, PLINQ uses the Pool.

Comment: qwerto: You never had the _wrong_ situation. Threads waiting for I/O is wasteful.

Comment: Well, if multiple threads can effectively reduce I/O latency costs, isn't it worth the trade?

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson: No, because they can be reduced further by using the correct async API which doesn't block on IO. Throwing extra threads at blocking code is poor-man's alternative to embracing async IO. Given that async is essentially compulsory on mobile and pretty slick with `async/await`, I don't think there's any reason not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with the following code:

```
var lines = Enumerable.Range(0, 200).ToArray();
int currentThreads = 0;
int maxThreads = 0;
object l = new object();
lines.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(100).ForAll(
    s =>
    {
        lock (l)
        {
            currentThreads++;
            if (currentThreads > maxThreads)
            {
                maxThreads = currentThreads;
                Console.WriteLine(maxThreads);
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        lock (l)
        {
            currentThreads--;
        }
    });

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(maxThreads);
```

Basically, it records the current number of concurrently executing iterations and then saves the maximum encountered value.

The results vary quite a bit, between 15 and 25, but it's always much more than the number of CPUs my computer has (4). Increasing the sleep time increases the maximum number of concurrent threads. So it looks like the limiting factor here is the `ThreadPool`: it will create new threads slowly, especially when jobs are being completed relatively quickly.

If you want to increase the number of threads used, you would need to use `SetMinThreads()` (not `SetMaxThreads()`). If I set the minimum to 50, the number of threads actually used is around 60.

But having dozens of threads that do nothing but wait is quite inefficient, especially when it comes to memory consumption. You should consider using asynchronous methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

PLINQ does not fit in this case.
I have found next article useful for me. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's about TPL Dataflow. But if you try to use that with blocking methods, I think it will behave the same as PLINQ, because it still uses `ThreadPool`.

Comment: svick, I have tested two approaches: PLINQ and TPL DataFlow with ActionBlock.
Both of them shows that I have 20 threads running but PLINQ executes these tasks sequental and TPL DataFlow runs them in parallel manner

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I suspect there is something wrong with your code.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: nope.

The amount of threading is simply up to the .Net Framework runtime. There is no developer control for controlling the number of threads for TPL (Task Parallel Library) usage.

**EDIT**

Thanks to some other feedback: it is actually possible--but not recommended--to manually control the number of threads in the ThreadPool, which PLINQ and TPL use.

It's my opinion that any parallelization problem needs to be carefully thought out, and carefully constructed and tested. There's a lot of subtlety in this.

Comment: Actually, with the default dispatcher, it's specifically a function of the ThreadPool, which ***can*** be controlled.

Comment: Well, don't leave me hanging. How?

Comment: With the ThreadPool.SetMinThreads and ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads methods. However, it's my belief that if you find yourself using these then there's a problem elsewhere in your code.